# No Sockets found: screen script called on startup

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sockets, startup

I have added a script called screen_tronserver.sh to the /etc/init.d/ directory. I have set the permissions so it is executable and called

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/screen_tronserver.sh defaults 100
```

to add the script to startup.
Inside the file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "creating screen and starting tron server..."
screen -S tronserver -m /home/pi/programming/tronserver/a.out
```

The a.out file is a compiled program which runs a server I have created. Now when I call

```
screen -ls
```

It says no sockets found. However, I have tried connecting to the server and it is successful, indicating the screen/socket is there somewhere, running in the background.

So why can I not see this mystical socket!?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo screen -ls`?

Comment: Do you know for a fact your server program isn't crashing? Screen will exit as soon as the command is done.

Comment: No the server is definitely up and running properly

Comment: Ooook this is very odd. First of all thank you for pointing that out. I did sudo screen -ls and it says the screen has been created but I am currently attached to it? (I forgot to mention I am using ssh on a raspberry pi.) The server is definitely running now as I have just tested it: However, all it does terminal wise is sits there printing a log of who's joined and left, and you cannot interact with the terminal. But the terminal I see now I can use normally and type commands in, even though I am apparently attached to the screen running the server? (Apologies for the jumbled explanation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Andrew is already alluding to, init scripts are run as root, and screens belong to different users. When you type `screen -ls` you will see the screens of the current user, not all screens on the system.

So yes, `sudo screen -ls` or `sudo screen -r` will do the trick.

**Edit** (for completeness and future reference): as pointed out by the OP, it is necessary to also add the `-d` flag to the screen command to detach right away in the init script, or else the screen will remain attached.

Comment: While this answer is correct in that I can see the screen, the thing that made it work properly was adding a -d to the screen command in the script. This means that upon starting up the pi is detached from the screen and everything works properly